# Suppose that A, B, and C are 3 independent events

Tags: probability, solution-verification

Suppose that A, B, and C are 3 independent events such that Pr(A)=1/4, Pr(B)=1/3 and Pr(C)=1/2.

a. Determine the probability that none of these events will occur.

Is it just:

$(1-P(A))(1-P(B))(1-P(C))=(3/4)(2/3)(1/2)=1/4$

b. Determine the probability that exactly one of these events will occur

$(P(A))(1-P(B))(1-P(C))+(1-P(A))(P(B))(1-P(C))+(1-P(A))(1-P(B))(P(C))$
$=(1/4)(2/3)(1/2)+(3/4)(1/3)(1/2)+(3/4)(2/3)(1/2)$
$=1/12+1/8+1/4$
$=2/24+3/24+6/24$
$=10/24$
$=5/12$

correction: 
=11/24

Does this look correct?

Comment: Everything up till the last step is correct. Check your addition.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are right.

For a, $P(A^cB^cC^c)=(1-P(A))(1-P(B))(1-P(C)) = 1/4$
since $A^c,B^c,C^c$ are also independent.

For b, $P(AB^cC^c+A^cBC^c+A^cB^cC)=P(A)(1-P(B))(1-P(C))+(1-P(A))(B)(1-P(C))+(1-P(A))(1-P(B))P(C) = 11/24$
since $(A,B^c,C^c)$ $(A^c,B,C^c)$ $(A^c,B^c,C)$ are also independent.